# hybris - Product Update API

Tags: web-services, rest, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to update Product information in hybris through REST Webservice API.

http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/catalogs/powertoolsProductCatalog/catalogversions/Online/products/2116275

I understand that we need to give the ProductDTO in the body of the PUT request. Please can someone help with an example? I am trying this in a REST Client and will be extending this in a .net environment.

Regards
Hari

Comment: Did you try the webservice trail on the Hybris wiki? https://wiki.hybris.com/display/tr52/Trail+~+Webservices

Comment: Yes.. I did.. I have got the answer too.. :-) Thanks..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have to give the PRODUCT DTO with the code. That made this work..

THanks..